# How perform the local libgit2 test cases

Tags: libgit2

I want to add an API like `git_merge_octopus_bases`, but how perform the local test cases? Could please show me some documents for this kind topics.

Comment: What do you mean by "permform" and "local"? How to run the existing test? How to write a new one? How to create the test fixtures?

Comment: @Aimeast The commment above is spot on. If you update you question to express in a more precise form what you're after, I'll gladly update my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[libgit2](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2)** project relies on the **[Clar](https://github.com/vmg/clar)** test framework.

You can get a first grasp of Clar features and usage in the **[Readme](https://github.com/vmg/clar/blob/master/README.md)** file.

The following documents should help one understand the basics of contributing to libgit2:

- **[Contributing guidelines](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/CONTRIBUTING.md)**
- **[LibGit2 conventions](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/CONVENTIONS.md)**

Comment: Thanks! That's my need. Looks very complicated